# MySQL - Query returning results in wrong order

Tags: mysql

The following MySQL queries below are returning results in different orders despite the "ORDER BY" being the same for both queries:

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| image_id        | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| property_id     | int(10)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| image_title     | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image_title_id  | int(10)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| image_index     | smallint(3) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| image_version   | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 2       |                |
| image_landscape | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| image_visible   | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| image_type      | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 3       |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**TEST 1**

Query:

```
SELECT image_id, room_text
FROM property_record_images
INNER JOIN property_data_rooms ON property_record_images.image_title_id = property_data_rooms.room_id
WHERE property_id = 1029
ORDER BY image_index
```

Result:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| image_id | room_text       |
+----------+-----------------+
|     2042 | Front elevation |
|     2043 | Garden to rear  |
|     2044 | Kitchen         |
|     2045 | Breakfast area  |
|     2046 | Lounge          |
|     2047 | Master bedroom  |
|     2048 | Studio          |
+----------+-----------------+
```

**TEST 2**

Query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(property_record_images.image_id) SEPARATOR '|')
FROM property_record_images
INNER JOIN property ON property_record_images.property_id = property.property_id
WHERE property_record_images.property_id = 1029
ORDER BY image_index
```

Result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(property_record_images.image_id) SEPARATOR '|') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2048|2047|2044|2045|2046|2043|2042                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is occurring with random records (different "property_id") so it's not an simple as just reversing the ORDER BY for the second query.

Any idea why this is happening and where I have gone wrong with the query?

Comment: sample outputs needed

Comment: Do you have some sample data as well as a table structure for us?

Comment: Is `image_index` type of INT?

Comment: add ORDER BY property_record_images.property_id,image_index

Comment: can you try
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(property_record_images.image_id) SEPARATOR '|')
FROM property_record_images
INNER JOIN property ON property_record_images.property_id = property.property_id
WHERE property_record_images.property_id = 1029
group by image_index
ORDER BY min(image_index) asc

Comment: or you can try
can you try SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(property_record_images.image_id) SEPARATOR '|') FROM property_record_images INNER JOIN property ON property_record_images.property_id = property.property_id WHERE property_record_images.property_id = 1029  ORDER BY image_index asc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

I think you should get ordered group concat by:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(property_record_images.image_id) ORDER BY image_index SEPARATOR '|')
FROM property_record_images
INNER JOIN property ON property_record_images.property_id = property.property_id
WHERE property_record_images.property_id = 1029
ORDER BY image_index
```

Comment: Ha! I just realised that too but you beat me to it! Thank you. :-)